# Remove all of a specific element with AngleSharp

Tags: html, element, anglesharp

Our CMS *Kentico* has moved from providing **HTMLAgilityPack** to **AngleSharp** in their latest edition. I would like to not have to reintroduce the **HTMLAgilityPack** if I can avoid it and stay with what is provided. I have HTML that can be sent by users through a DevExpress HTML Editor. I want to strip out all span tags from that HTML and potentially other tags so that Google Structured Data can handle it. I don't see any examples of how to remove ALL elements from a block of HTML like I had with my three lines of code in the **HTMLAgilityPack**. Does anyone have a good example?

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure I can follow. Maybe one of the following two examples covers your use case.

Remove all span tags of the current document (note: could be also a single line).

```
foreach (var element in document.QuerySelectorAll("span"))
{
    element.Remove();
}
```

Remove everything from a given element:

```
element.TextContent = "";
```

Alternatively, you can make a loop here, but the above one is usually the simplest / and quite efficient.

Hope this helps!